# Post on a fan page using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, gecko, geckofx

I am making an application to post on my fan pages, as I sign, I list the fan pages, it's all right.

I'm just not able to put the text on the facebook text box.

Look here:

```
<div data-block="true" data-offset-key="72l55-0-0" class="_209g _2vxa">
<span data-offset-key="72l55-0-0">
    <span data-text="true">I NEED TO PUT TEXT HERE!!!</span>
</span>
```

```
HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
            foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
            {
                if (item.GetAttribute("classname") == "_209g _2vxa")
                {
                    item.InnerText = "oiii " + DateTime.Now;
                    item.InvokeMember("click");
                    //SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the InnerText of the div. And then clicking on the same div? How about getting the proper span, for example:

var span = item.GetElementsByTagName("span").First().GetElementsByTagName("span").First();
span.InnerText = "whatever";

And then click a submit button?

Comment: Hello Friend
Yes when I click on Div he opens the box for typing, need to play a text in this typing box.